# How to use "ref" to refer an element in React Stateless Component

Tags: reactjs, focus, ref

I was trying to implement focus for the Submit button with Ref. I wanted to omit refering elements by ID.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const LabelComponent = () => {

  const createButton = enableCreateButton()
    ? <button ref={(input) => { this.createLabelBtn = input }} >Submit</button>
    : <button disabled ref={(input) => { this.createLabelBtn = input }} >Submit</button>

  const createLabelBtn = useRef();

  const focusCreateBtn = (e) => {
    if ((e.key === 'Enter') && (newLabel.name !== '')) {
      this.createLabelBtn.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='create-label-container'>
      <input type='text'
        onKeyDown={(e) => { focusCreateBtn(e) }}
      />

      {createButton}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It gives following error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'createLabelBtn' of undefined**

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'createLabelBtn' of undefined**

What could be the issue here.?

Comment: Replace `this.createLabelBtn` by `createLabelBtn.current`

Comment: @SonDang It works. But it's not only focus the button, it perform button click. Do you have any idea.?

Comment: It's probably because the programmatically focus is called on enter keydown event, which will fire the enter key press event after focus (which behaves  as button click). In `focusCreateBtn` function, try calling `e.preventDefault()` before `createLabelBtn.current.focus()`

Comment: @SonDang That was the exact issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components are instanceless, therefore, no `this` to bind anything to or call upon. Set the `ref` prop on the button as so `ref={createLabelBtn}`, and to set the focus you need to access `createLabelBtn.current` to get at the current value of the ref.

```
export const LabelComponent = ({ enableCreateButton }) => {
  const createLabelBtn = useRef(null);

  const focusCreateBtn = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      createLabelBtn.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="create-label-container">
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={focusCreateBtn} />
      <button
        // upon being focused upon, console log proof
        onFocus={() => console.log("Submit Focused!")}
        disabled={!enableCreateButton}
        ref={createLabelBtn}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit strange-wood-chou6]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const LabelComponent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const createButton = true ? (
    <button
      ref={input => {
        createLabelBtn.current = input;
      }}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  ) : (
    <button
      disabled
      ref={input => {
        createLabelBtn.current = input;
      }}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  );

  const createLabelBtn = useRef();

  const focusCreateBtn = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && name !== "") {
      createLabelBtn.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="create-label-container">
      <input
        type="text"`enter code here`
        value={name}
        onChange={e => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyDown={e => {
          focusCreateBtn(e);
        }}
      />

      {createButton}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LabelComponent;
```

Comment: It works. But it's not only focus the button, it perform button click. Do you have any idea.?